# Excel VBA Selecting Range in different workbook in order to sort

Tags: vba, excel

and first let me thank everyone at stackoverflow.  Google has led me to this forum many times in my search for solutions to Excel VBA problems and I have usually found what I needed here.  That said,

I am in the process of building a macro or set of macros that take selected data from one spreadheet and copies it to another worksheet in a newly created workbook.  I'm down to the last piece of the puzzle of sorting specific ranges and keep getting a Run Time Error '1004' when trying to select a specific range in the new workbook which I then want to sort.  I have tried multiple solutions both using code similar to the sample below as well as using Cells to define the range.  I have exausted Google at this point in my search for a solution.

```
With nfmBook.Worksheets("Reading NFM")
nfmBook.Sheets("Reading NFM").Activate
nfmBook.Sheets("Reading NFM").Select

nfmBook.Sheets("Reading NFM").Range("B" & sortStart & ":K" & sortEnd).Select

Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("K") _
    , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers, DataOption2 _
    :=xlSortTextAsNumbers

    Cells(nfmRow, 11).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Cells(sortStart,11),Cells(sortEnd,11))"


End With
```

Comment: Are you certain that the variables `sortStart` and `sortEnd` return the correct beginning and end rows?

Comment: In your `.Sort` line, preface every Range with a . so that it is `.Range(..` and inherits the proper workbook and worksheet from your `With` statement.  Otherwise it will try to use a range that is from a worksheet that doesn't exist in the `nfmBook` and that it what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tryed this way? (UPDATED)

```
Set SortRange = nfmBook.Sheets("Reading NFM").Range("B" & SortStart & ":K" & SortEnd)
SortRange.Sort Key1:=SortRange.Cells(1, 1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
Key2:=SortRange.Cells(1, 10), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
```

SortRange.Cells(1, 1) is the first cell of the first row of the range = "B" & SortStart

SortRange.Cells(1, 10)  is the tenth cell of the first row of the range = "K" & SortStart

I hope this works (for me it worked)

Comment: This code still has the same problem where the Key1 and Key2 ranges aren't qualified to the appropriate workbook and sheet.  As such the code will try to use the `ActiveSheet` which will likely cause the same error